# How to add validation in Orbeon Form to not allow any image/jpeg image/png

Tags: validation, attachment, orbeon

I am creating an orbeon form where i have added attachment button to upload document. I have set it as mandatory but wondering if we can check and validate the documents allowed to upload.

I do not want to allow users to upload image/jpeg, image/png. image/jpg

Any help would be appreciable.

[I have attached image here for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nM66.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is with Form Runner, you can add a validation formula:

```
not(contains(@mediatype, 'image/jpeg')) and
not(contains(@mediatype, 'image/png'))  and
not(contains(@mediatype, 'image/jpg'))
```

This would still allow a malicious user to upload images by faking the upload content type.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, though I tried the validation condition and it did failed. Is there something else should i consider?

Comment: How did it fail? I just tried this in Form Builder and get the expected result.